# Is it fine to make CloudBlobContainer object transient?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have a service class which include a method called GetContainer,

```
    private CloudBlobContainer GetContainer(string blobConnectionString, string blobContainerName)
    {
        var storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(blobConnectionString);
        var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        return blobClient.GetContainerReference(blobContainerName);
    }
```

now from service method is calling this method every time it need to perform an operation like,

```
    public Task CopyAsync(string blobConnectionString, string blobContainerName, string sourceFile, string destinationFile)
    {
        var container = GetContainer(blobConnectionString, blobContainerName);
        return CopyInternalAsync(container, sourceFile, destinationFile);
    }

    private Task CopyInternalAsync(CloudBlobContainer container, string sourceFile, string destinationFile)
    {
        var sourceBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(sourceFile);
        var destinationBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(destinationFile);
        return destinationBlob.StartCopyFromBlobAsync(sourceBlob);
    }
```

I can make the CloudBlobContainer singleton like web-api sample doing it [here](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/sourcecontrol/latest#Samples/WebApi/AzureBlobsFileUploadSample/AzureBlobsFileUpload/Controllers/FilesController.cs). But the problem is that my blob connection-string and container-name is not fixed. Should I use ConcurrentDictionary or is it fine to make CloudBlobContainer transient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GetContainerReference` and `GetBlockBlobReference` are both very lightweight operations - neither talks  to Azure until you actually perform an operation such as the `StartCopyFromBlobAsync` that you do above.

See https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/master/Lib/Common/Blob/CloudBlobClient.Common.cs#L288:

```
public CloudBlobContainer GetContainerReference(string containerName)
{
    CommonUtility.AssertNotNullOrEmpty("containerName", containerName);
    return new CloudBlobContainer(containerName, this);
}
```

and https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/master/Lib/Common/Blob/CloudBlobContainer.Common.cs#L82:

```
internal CloudBlobContainer(string containerName, CloudBlobClient serviceClient) : this(new BlobContainerProperties(), new Dictionary<string, string>(), containerName, serviceClient)
{
}

internal CloudBlobContainer(BlobContainerProperties properties, IDictionary<string, string> metadata, string containerName, CloudBlobClient serviceClient)
{
    this.StorageUri = NavigationHelper.AppendPathToUri(serviceClient.StorageUri, containerName);
    this.ServiceClient = serviceClient;
    this.Name = containerName;
    this.Metadata = metadata;
    this.Properties = properties;
}
```

It's just creating an object and returning it to you - treating it as transient shouldn't be a problem.